Is there any way to limit URI access in X-UI?
Is there any solutions in X-UI to limit user access to specific URLs? For example, I need my users to access only 10 specific URLs, and any other URL should not be accessible through the X-UI connection.
I just searched the web but couldn't find any solutions!
